# PyQT QTreeview + QPushButton/QCombobox signals

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

I'm trying to load a serries of files that are dics and then load arrays from within dics to my QTreeView and then be able to edit these dics. I have a problem when it comes to connecting signal as it connects all buttons to 1 data - last created one. If I load 20 arrays from 1 dict I should be able to click on each array and print its name. Right now it just prints last added name.

Here is the code:

```
def add_data(self):
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dat_folder):
            for file_inx, file_name in enumerate(files):
                ''' loading file '''
                ''' creating data'''

                if len(data[1]) >0:
                    #file_inx = file_inx + 1 # not sure if I need this tbd.
                    job = QStandardItem(project_name)
                    self.model.setItem(file_inx,0,job)
                    self.model.setItem(file_inx, 1, QStandardItem(project_time_day+"  "+project_time_time))
                    for inx, layers in enumerate(data[1]):
                        child1 = QStandardItem(layers["Name"])
                        child2 = QStandardItem("Push Button or Combobox or QCheckBox")
                        job.insertRow(inx,[child1, child2])
                        b=QPushButton("TestPrint"+str(inx))
                        b.clicked.connect(lambda: self.printData(child1.text(),layers["Name"]))

                        a = self.model.index(file_inx, 0) #find parent
                        i = a.child(inx,7) # find parented location
                        self.tv_job_list.setIndexWidget(i,b) # replace child2 with QPushButton - b 

    def printData(self,value,name):
        print value,name
```

Here is how the QTreeView looks like, each job can have hundreds of job_names and there can be hundreds of Job_01 etc etc... Its a big list :- ) 
1 file on HDD creates 1 parent that create child jobs.

```
Parent > JOB_01
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     ... x 1000 Childs...


Parent > JOB_01
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     Child > Job_Name | Job_Submit_Date | QComboBox | QPushButton | QCheckBox
     ... x 1000 Childs...
```

Comment: You reinitialize the QPushButton every time the inside for loop loops, so it makes sense that only the last array would show. You override the first 19 in the for loop so the button is only connected to the 20th array.

Comment: Yes I know thats the problem I'm facing... how do I NOT override it?

Comment: Take it out of the loop and instead connect the button to a method that will loop through `data[1]` and print out the data.

Comment: Humh, I'm lost, how would the code know which button I clicked if I'm looping over entire list of data[1]? Not to mention that data can have hundreds of entries... I'm a bit lost sorry.... What I need to get is Row 1st entry/ row entry changed(as it can be combobox/check box/ ) so then I can go to dict and do the change there... I don't  want to loop over entire data. Just specific data for specific row...

Comment: How many buttons do you want? Do you want 20 buttons if there are 20 data points, or do you want one button that you can press to get the next data point? I'm not quite sure what you're asking to be honest

Comment: 1 button/Combo/checkbox + per child. I have upgraded my question with extra info. I'm also wondering if I should use QTreeWidget instead of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partial :

```
  b = QPushButton(str(inx))
  b.clicked.connect(partial(self.printData,child1.text()))
```